# need help in thumbnail size player for flv?

Tags: flash

We need a thumbnail size flv player just like in bing.

Like if you hover over this bing search results [Bing search results](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=cat&go=&qs=n&form=VBREQY&pq=cat&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=)

Is there already an existing player or we will need to make our own?

Comment: Like this size?
http://darkshadow.elementfx.com/sd.html

Comment: @JamesDyson is that your script on the work in the link you gave? will you share us the code for that and also the swf/player you used?

Comment: I sure will, I just need to get home to copy that script for you and I will pop in a here straight away as an answer

Answer (score 0):

yes ,its possible ,just give the appropriate height and width to the video player object created .You will see a small sized video player (just the same you have seen in the link in the comment to your question).
Also while embedding the flash file to your web page ,give the above specified height ,width while embedding .This will ensure that your div (containing flash)is not bigger than your video frame.
Cheers

Comment: Try this and let me know.I have done it recently for my project

Comment: a side issue. We want it to work just like as bing where when you hover the image thumb will be replaced by a video object. Have you tried that before?

Comment: I'll make a script for you examine @Redhot